# Its Possible to connect multiple requirements to one requirementHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I try to connect multi requirements to one requirementHandler becouse  I don't want to write the same code several times. In first requirement i use many requirementHandlers. And in secound requirement i want to use  requirementHandlers with the same logic . I have to create new handlers with the same code and new generic type ? Is it correct with solid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to handle multiple requirements if you implement `IAuthorizationHandler` instead of inheriting from `AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>`.
Since you can't inherit from multiple classes, implementing the interface seems like the logical way.

You'll need to implement `HandleAsync` and check there if the requirement is one of those the handler supports.
If it is, run it through your logic.
You can see what `AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>` does: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/77599445aabd7bf357feb5cf8dfec7187148f1af/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationHandler.cs.
For reference, this is how it filters to the requirement type you specified:

```cs
public virtual async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
{
    foreach (var req in context.Requirements.OfType<TRequirement>())
    {
        await HandleRequirementAsync(context, req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but how pass resources to startUp class. Becouse therei must declare services.addScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, Handler<TRequirement, TResouces>> . But how to send TResouces to this handler ?